# Find all filenames in multiple directories inside a parent directory

Tags: bash, grep, find

I have a parent directory say `parent` and there are multiple directories inside `parent` named as `child-1`, `child-2`, ... 
Inside the parent directory including the child directories, I want to find all files with the extension `*.txt`.
How can I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: You have already tagged the question `find`.  It might be worthwhile checking out `man find`.

Answer (score 1):

Run the below find command to find `.txt` files inside your parent directory(including subfolders)

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt"
```

OR

```
find /path/to/parent -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt"
```

Comment: I worked but I am getting outputs in random order...can I get them in specific order??

Comment: specific order means?

Comment: means that the folder are searched randomly, not `child-1` then `child-2` and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Use find command say,

`find $path/parent/ -name "*.txt" -print 2>/dev/null`

```
     1st argument: path where files needs to be searched
     2nd argument: name or pattern of files
     3rd argument: printing the output
     4th argument: 2>/dev/null :dump the error dustbin /dev/null
```